# Sublime Text 3 texlive output from compilation:

Tags: texlive, compiling, sublime-text

I am trying to run sublime text 3 texlive on a windows 10 x64 system. When I compile I get the following message:

```
[Compiling C:\Users\devin\Documents\LEGrp\tex\setup_instructions\ISUR setup instructions.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking latexmk... done.

Output from compilation:
```

but no pdf file is created or opened. I am using SumatraPDF. I have tried searching for this issue but without any explicit errors it is hard to debug. In my LaTeXTools.sublime-settings file in the "windows" section I have :

```
"windows": {

        // Path used when invoking tex & friends; "" is fine for MiKTeX
        // For TeXlive 2011 (or other years) use
        // "texpath" : "C:\\texlive\\2011\\bin\\win32;$PATH",
        "texpath" : "C:\\texlive\\2015\\bin\\win32;$PATH",
        // TeX distro: "miktex" or "texlive"
        "distro" : "texlive",
        // Command to invoke Sumatra. If blank, "SumatraPDF.exe" is used (it has to be on your PATH)
        "sumatra": "",
        // Command to invoke Sublime Text. Used if the keep_focus toggle is true.
        // If blank, "subl.exe" or "sublime_text.exe" will be used.
        "sublime_executable": "",
        // how long (in seconds) to wait after the jump_to_pdf command completes
        // before switching focus back to Sublime Text. This may need to be
        // adjusted depending on your machine and configuration.
        "keep_focus_delay": 0.5
    },
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting the `Output from compilation:` line indicates that a log file wasn't generated, most likely because there was some problem launching LaTeX or latexmk. Most likely, since there is no output, there was some problem running running `latexmk` itself, i.e. the executable couldn't be found had some error running. There may be some useful information in the Sublime console. To see, use the **View** menu and select the **Show Console** option.

Another thing you could try is running `latexmk` from the command prompt. The command LaTeXTools uses looks something like this:

```
C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\latexmk.exe -cd -f -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "C:\Users\devin\Documents\LEGrp\tex\setup_instructions\ISUR setup instructions.tex"
```

Try running that from the command prompt and see what happens.

I suppose the most likely cause is that you've installed the minimal install of TeXLive, in which case you will need to run `tlmgr install latexmk` from an elevated command prompt.